# Simple event in C# for MyControl

Tags: c#

I want to Create Event for a time that  AllowDrop Changes in MyControl.

In MyControl :

```
public event EventHandler AllowDropChanged;

private void MyControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AllowDropChanged +=new EventHandler(MyControl_AllowDropChanged);
}
private void MyControl_AllowDropChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        MessageBox.Show("Dropping Changed");

}
```

How Can I Raise My Event ?

Comment: I tell you one more time...stop putting `Everlasting` in front of your questions. We're a Q&A site, even `Hi` and `Thank you` is already seen as unnecessary clutter. And learn how to use the markup, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck, AllowDrop is a virtual property.  Which makes it very easy to raise the event, just override the property and raise the event in the setter.  The boilerplate code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyControl : Control {

    public event EventHandler AllowDropChanged;

    protected void OnAllowDropChanged(EventArgs e) {
        var handler = AllowDropChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    public override bool AllowDrop {
        get { return base.AllowDrop; }
        set {
            if (value != base.AllowDrop) {
                base.AllowDrop = value;
                OnAllowDropChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (AllowDropChanged != null)
{
    AllowDropChanged(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to add an event handler in your control's code. It should be handled in the code where ever your control is used. So, you would have something like this

<strike>AllowDropChanged +=new EventHandler(MyControl_AllowDropChanged);</strike>

```
  public event EventHandler AllowDropChanged;


   private void OnAllowDropChanged()
   {
       if(AllowDropChanged!=null)
       {
           AllowDropChanged(this,new EventArgs());
       }
   }
```

Comment: I Should Check the Condition : AllowDrop==!AllowDrop to raise this event . where is the place to check this .

Answer (score 0):

Events can be called just like a function, but you should customarily check if it's null first (which checks if there are any handlers bound to it):

```
if (AllowDropChanged != null) AllowDropChanged(this, new EventArgs());
```

You haven't specified in your question what the event is for or where it comes from, so there's really no more information I can give. Just put that line wherever you want the event to be fired.